# Stuck threads on weblogic - possibly due to CFX / Spring

Tags: spring, multithreading, web-services, weblogic

We are seeing stuck threads on Weblogic in Production environment. 
It cannot be replicated in Development environment.

We have 1 Web Service (API) that encounters stuck threads more often. 
Need help in replicating the issue in Development and a fix for it.

It looks like there is some issue with CFX / Spring framework we are using. 
CFX version: 3.1.4, 
Spring version: 4.2.2.RELEASE, 
Sprig Security: 4.0.3.RELEASE

Below is a snippet from thread dump. Please let me know of any inputs on how to fix the issue with lock on the Phase Interceptor

> at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
>
> at
>   com.minervanetworks.xtv.stb.service.impl.ClientContentManagerImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$115ca042.edgeBrowse()
>
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor352.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>
> at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
>
> at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
>   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200)
>
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
>
> at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
>
> at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>
> - locked <0x000000013132eca0> (a org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain)
>
> at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
>
> at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
>
> at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
>
> at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)

Thanks, 
Sheldon

Comment: Please read about how to **format** your question. Just dumping raw text like this isn't exactly great. You want us to spend our time to help you; so you please spend some time to make that as easy and straight forward as possible!

Comment: I believe that i have formatted the question. Basically, i dont know what the issue is, apart from the fact that we see stuck threads in Weblogic (Application server) console. On checking the thread dump, it shows a lock on the phase interceptor. I did some research online and found that there could be some issue with CFX / Spring framework. I would be grateful if someone who is aware of Weblogic, Web Services, CFX & Spring can verify the issue with stuck threads and give any suggestions that might help resolve the issue. I can provide any additional information as needed.

Comment: Avoid putting more information into comments. If something is missing from the question, edit the question and add what is missing please!